# Javascript DataLayer Fetch from

Tags: javascript, html, google-tag-manager

I'd like to pull data from my HTML code into my dataLayer (Google Tag Manager).

The html code is something like this:

```
<body class="portal sessions" data-place="hun">...</body>
```

And the Javascript Code is something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var lang_log = document.getElementsByClassName("portal");
  dataLayer.push({
    "language_login":lang_log
})
</script>
```

What I'd try is to give to the lang_log variable the "hun" value and I'd try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var lang_log = document.getElementsByClassName("portal")['data-place'];
  dataLayer.push({
    "language_login":lang_log
})
</script>
```

But it's not working.
Any ideas?

---

Any help or advice is apprecaited, Thank you in advance.

Comment: You might try the native solution with a DOM type variable, a selector that looks for body.portal and "data-place" as attribute name - this should return the value of the attribute without custom JS.

Comment: thanks, I'll try this one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.getElementsByClassName("portal")` returns an array-like collection of elements.

You can get the first element of this collection  with `document.getElementsByClassName("portal")[0]`.

To [access the data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes#JavaScript_access), use `document.getElementsByClassName("portal")[0].dataset.place`.

```js
var AdataLayer = [];
var lang_log = document.getElementsByClassName("portal")[0].dataset.place;
AdataLayer.push({
  "language_login":lang_log
})
console.log(AdataLayer);
console.log(AdataLayer[0].language_login);
```

```html
<body class="portal sessions" id="portal" data-place="hun">...</body>
```

Comment: thanks a lot! this is the answer to the issue - I missed that data-place is actually a data attribute!

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

the JS should be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var lang_log = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].getAttribute("data-locale");
  dataLayer.push({
    "language_login":lang_log
})
</script>
```

Still investigating in why the first version did not work!